# My Mesh Distorts When Switching To Object Mode?

Tags: mesh, distort

[image]

I have no clue what I did wrong, and I am very new to blender so help please. This mesh is rigged to a skeleton that was rigged and fully functioning, until I edited the shape of the mesh to work on details of the deer, and now every time I exit object mode, the mesh distorts.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your rig is not in your 't-pose', meaning you adjusted the bones and didn't clear the adjustments you made, meaning the bones' rotations are applying to the mesh. If you want, you can either clear the keyframes on your rig to fix that, or I think leave your armature in edit mode. Your mesh isn't broke, it just looks like the rig is properly affecting it.